# Using Waypoints in Routes - Directions Service Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

If I add waypoints to my google map - function calcRoute not working.
How to set waypoints correctly?

Thanks.

```
<script>
      var directionDisplay;
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      var map;

      function initialize() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom:55,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          center: chicago
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      }

      function calcRoute() {

        var start = "Berlin";
        var end = "Paris";
        var waypts = ["Frankfurt"];

    var request = {
            origin:start,
            destination:end,
            waypoints:waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=pl#Waypoints

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the documentation that you reference, the string "Frankfurt" is not a valid [waypoint](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pl#DirectionsWaypoint).

A single waypoint with the location "Frankfurt" would look like this:

```
[{ location: "Frankfurt", stopover: false}]
```

with the value of stopover set appropriately.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/hus4wvf8/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: chicago
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {

  var start = "Berlin";
  var end = "Paris";
  var waypts = [{
    location: "Frankfurt",
    stopover: false
  }];

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else alert("directions request failed, status=" + status)
  });
}
initialize();
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", "sans-serif";
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Directions Service</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=&v=weekly"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below script might help you.

```
    <script>     
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    function showmap() 
    {   
          jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getLocations", 
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(data){         
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);   
          var LocationData=[];
          var i=0; 
            obj.forEach(function(entry) { 
              entry.forEach(function(test){                        
              LocationData[i] = test
              i++;                
            });                 
            }); 
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(LocationData[0].latitude,LocationData[0].longitude),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          });

          directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
          directionsDisplay.setMap(map); 
          var start = new google.maps.LatLng(LocationData[0].latitude,LocationData[0].longitude); 
          var end = new google.maps.LatLng(LocationData[obj[0].length-1].latitude,LocationData[obj[0].length-1].longitude); 
          var waypts = [];
          var upto = obj[0].length-1;
          if(upto > 7)
            upto = 7;
          if(obj[0].length > 2) {
          for (var i = 1; i < upto; i++) {
              waypts.push({
                location: new google.maps.LatLng(LocationData[i].latitude,LocationData[i].longitude),
                stopover: true
              });
            }
          }
          calcRoute(start,end,waypts);
        }
         });        
    }

    function calcRoute(start,end,waypts) { 
      var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: end,
          waypoints: waypts,
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Just code without explanation is not the most helpful answer.